# Error in submitting form Laravel and CKEditor

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

[image]

Hello i am trying to integrate CKEditor with `laravel-elfinder` package in L4 
it is giving me an error...

P.S form is working fine without CKEditor...
any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a same problem.

- Login to cpanel
- search for mod security
- turn off the mod_security

you can also turn it off using htaccess file just paste the following code and upload it your server

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

**P.S**

Mod_security is an Extra layer of security... you may be in serious trouble after removing or disabling it.

**reference**
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/modsecurity/disable-mod-security-via-modsec-manager